# Как в python создать свою команду типа -help?

Tags: python-3.x

Всем добрый день! Есть такая задачка: написать свою консольную программу в python. Программа будет называться scanipcams. При запуске программы будет выводиться: "для справки введите команду -h ,-help", будут отображаться следующие команды программы. Как сделать следующее :

```
scanipcams -ip [ человек будет указывать ip-адрес] -scan run
```

Я пока что застрял на выводе справки. Писал следующее:

```
if str(input())=="-h" && str(input())=="-help":
   print (""" 
    -ip           Необходимо указать ip-адрес локального сервера
    -scan         для того чтобы запустить сканер, необходимо указать команду run
""")
```

А дальше как делать?

```
if str(input())=="-ip":
   print("Вы указали следующий ip")
```

При выполнении кода, при указании `-h`, он выводит справку. Если я так же делаю проверку ввода команд, то он почему-то не одной строкой принимает ввод команд как должно быть, типа: `scanipcams -ip [ человек будет указывать ip-адрес] -scan run` 
а поблочно.

Помогите разобраться....

Comment: Вот тут написано: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/462007/

Comment: ``if str(input())=="-h" && str(input())=="-help":`` - это неправильно. Не может быть введено одновременно ``-h`` и ``-help``. И конвертировать input() в str необязательно. Он и так всегда строка.

Comment: Хорошо я понял спасибо , но как мне сделал ввод команд в одну тройку ?

Comment: Вам нужен разбор ключей командной строки (до запуска программы, например в cmd или bash), или команд введенных после запуска программы?

Comment: insolor , после запуска программы ..

Comment: для создания своих аргументов команд видимо придется мне использовать модуль      import sys

Comment: Спасибо вам всем за помощь разобрался....

Comment: Отвечен? И где же ответ?